# Apple Watch | installing the app from XCode taking really long time

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I am trying to install my app on a real Apple Watch device and every time I compile it takes more than an hour in fresh install. Later installs happen in minutes. However, it's very common to clean the build or delete the earlier version to have a fresh install. I am wondering if I am missing something obvious here. What is the average time of compiling and installing the app on Apple Watch? Please help as I am losing hours and hours in just seeing the compilation.

Here are the details: Xcode 9.2, Watch Series - 1(v4.2),2(v3.0),3 (v4.2)

Comment: This obviously depends on several factors, most importantly the size of your app and your network speed. You should test the installation from another computer on the same network and with similar hardware specs, if the speed is the same, there's most probably nothing wrong with your setup.

Comment: you may have many assets in the apple watch app + extension. start with that. how big does the apple watch app get?